# Show that the graph $G(T)$ of a linear operator $T: X \rightarrow Y$ is a vector subspace of $X\times Y$

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that the graph $G(T)$ of a linear operator $T: X \rightarrow Y$ is a vector subspace of $X \times Y$.

Would I want to somehow use the closed graph theorem to do this? I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks.

Comment: No you simply have to prove $G(T)$ is closed under addition of vectors and scalar multiplication. There's no topology involved here, so no closed graph theorem needed.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try. Appreciate it

Comment: @MathIsHard: Did you finish this problem?